# Verify if a file is SQL or verify its syntax

Tags: oracle, jenkins, gitlab, devops

I'm implementing DevOps with Oracle and Jenkins, I use a Gitlab repository for scripts .sql (PL/SQL and ORDS), I want to verify if a file is uploaded and trigger pipeline is indeed a SQL file and verify its syntax to avoid execute all pipeline if it is a wrong file. Exists some Oracle command or script that do this? (I find EXPLAIN PLAN FOR but it doesn't work with PL/SQL blocks and ORDS)

Thank you

Comment: for your ORDS stuff...what is it exactly that you have? ORDS PL/SQL API calls? Something else?

Comment: I have PL/SQL scripts to modify schema and also ORDS to create API calls, both types are .sql files, when a database user modify its files, a Jenkins pipeline is executed and apply this sql files in database, i only want to verify if uploads files are SQL files, and not other script types (python, rb, etc.).

Comment: so the ORDS objects/files are also just sql scripts then

Comment: Yes sir, by the way, i like your blog, lately I visit it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
script
   var input = 'select * from emp';
   var ParsedSql = Java.type('oracle.dbtools.parser.plsql.ParsedSql');
   var parsed = new ParsedSql(input);
   var root = parsed.parse();
   root.printTree();
/
```

[image]

The other useful ParsedSql methods:

- getInput()
- getSrc()
- getRoot()
- getSyntaxError()